# I cannot open all the JetBrains' applications after I deleted some system items on my Macbook

Tags: intellij-idea, nswindow, dylib

I cannot open Intellij, Pycharm, Clion, Outlook as well as Android Studio after I used PowerMyMac to delete many trashes and some system items on my Mac. Here are some error logs. I presume there are some files missing from my Mac and I do not know how to fix it.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               idea [17025]
Path:                  /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
Identifier:            com.jetbrains.intellij
Version:               2022.2.3 (IU-222.4345.14)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-11-10 14:54:18.3459 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     7.0 (20P420)
Anonymous UUID:        33D9A4C3-8F13-E387-04B2-53BD5DB29E68


Time Awake Since Boot: 6700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81080343b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff810352e25 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81082b5d6 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
3   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138d2161 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 307
4   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138bef4f -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1247
5   AppKit                              0x00007ff813a59412 -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50
6   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138bea69 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
7   AppKit                              0x00007ff813a593cb -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 59
8   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138bcf88 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 354
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff81388b42a -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 222
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff81388ab9c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 476
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff81387f67f loadNib + 420
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff81387ea67 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 737
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff81387e691 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
14  AppKit                              0x00007ff813bd17a0 -[NSAlert init] + 101
15  idea                                0x000000010483ca48 -[Launcher buildArgsFor:] + 1416
16  idea                                0x000000010483cf54 -[Launcher launch] + 340
17  Foundation                          0x00007ff8115da82c __NSThread__start__ + 1009
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8106b0259 _pthread_start + 125
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8106abc7b thread_start + 15


Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff8106716a2 mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81067f67d mach_msg2_internal + 82
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81067871a mach_msg_overwrite + 723
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff810671989 mach_msg + 19
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff81078ad0e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff81078977a __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff810788bb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
7   idea                                   0x10483bf22 main + 370
8   dyld                                0x7ff81037f310 start + 2432

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106abc58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106abc58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81067830e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106aff7b pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff8105f9ca5 abort + 123
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81066a082 abort_message + 241
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81065b23d demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff81035a023 _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff8106694a5 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81066bd05 __cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 27
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81066bccc __cxa_throw + 116
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff810352f23 objc_exception_throw + 302
10  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff81082b5d6 -[NSException raise] + 9
11  AppKit                              0x7ff8138d2161 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 307
12  AppKit                              0x7ff8138bef4f -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1247
13  AppKit                              0x7ff813a59412 -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50
14  AppKit                              0x7ff8138bea69 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
15  AppKit                              0x7ff813a593cb -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 59
16  AppKit                              0x7ff8138bcf88 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 354
17  AppKit                              0x7ff81388b42a -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 222
18  AppKit                              0x7ff81388ab9c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 476
19  AppKit                              0x7ff81387f67f loadNib + 420
20  AppKit                              0x7ff81387ea67 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 737
21  AppKit                              0x7ff81387e691 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
22  AppKit                              0x7ff813bd17a0 -[NSAlert init] + 101
23  idea                                   0x10483ca48 -[Launcher buildArgsFor:] + 1416
24  idea                                   0x10483cf54 -[Launcher launch] + 340
25  Foundation                          0x7ff8115da82c __NSThread__start__ + 1009
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106b0259 _pthread_start + 125
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106abc7b thread_start + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106abc58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8106abc58 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000070000fb3f000  rcx: 0x000070000fb3cb98  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000002103  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000fb3cbc0  rsp: 0x000070000fb3cb98
   r8: 0x000070000fb3ca60   r9: 0x00007ff81066cf9b  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000002103  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007ff81067830e  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00007ff8503116c8
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148 
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7ff810670000 -     0x7ff8106a9ff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <0c2fd2c9-777c-3355-b70f-7b1b6e9d1b0b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7ff81070c000 -     0x7ff810ba4fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <dbc459f3-81bb-398a-8f74-3f7392392bb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x104838000 -        0x10483ffff com.jetbrains.intellij (2022.2.3) <a4de0629-7887-3eaf-b883-5ae080407e51> /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
    0x7ff810379000 -     0x7ff81040d54f dyld (*) <28fd2071-57f3-3873-87bf-e4f674a82de6> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff8106aa000 -     0x7ff8106b5ff7 libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <13b5e252-77d1-31e1-888d-1c5f4426ea87> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7ff810578000 -     0x7ff810600fff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <5efaf10b-2ec1-32ed-b077-80125e552c8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7ff81065a000 -     0x7ff81066fff7 libc++abi.dylib (*) <68c48086-22ee-31c9-a457-954d641b9328> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7ff81033d000 -     0x7ff810378fd8 libobjc.A.dylib (*) <aca7ef61-2853-3699-8c1f-1c0ab93ad6be> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7ff81386d000 -     0x7ff814871ff6 com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <817d572e-eb8c-3999-b7a0-68e1c4b47266> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7ff811582000 -     0x7ff811f93ff6 com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <eca88952-d3af-357e-80d8-4d31b2dc0c26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=402.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=402.2M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.1G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
ColorSync                          216K       23 
CoreGraphics                         4K        1 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           248.3M       43 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       10 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         480.0M        4         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        6 
Stack                             18.0M        6 
VM_ALLOCATE                         20K        4 
__CTF                               756        1 
__DATA                            15.5M      302 
__DATA_CONST                      13.9M      182 
__DATA_DIRTY                       652K      107 
__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 
__LINKEDIT                       181.4M        5 
__OBJC_RO                         65.1M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1982K        2 
__TEXT                           220.8M      324 
dyld private memory                256K        1 
mapped file                       67.6M       15 
shared memory                      764K       15 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.7G     1057 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   890.8M     1057 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"idea","timestamp":"2022-11-10 14:54:18.00 +0800","app_version":"2022.2.3","slice_uuid":"a4de0629-7887-3eaf-b883-5ae080407e51","build_version":"IU-222.4345.14","platform":1,"bundleID":"com.jetbrains.intellij","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)","roots_installed":0,"name":"idea","incident_id":"F4724040-D11B-4FCA-B885-CE4404C7464E"}
{
  "uptime" : 6700,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro15,1",
  "coalitionID" : 5695,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 13.0.1",
    "build" : "22A400",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-11-10 14:54:18.3459 +0800",
  "incident" : "F4724040-D11B-4FCA-B885-CE4404C7464E",
  "pid" : 17025,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2022-11-10 14:54:18.1584 +0800",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 6757213702141,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 6757400863702,
  "procName" : "idea",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/IntelliJ IDEA.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/idea",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"2022.2.3","CFBundleVersion":"IU-222.4345.14","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.jetbrains.intellij"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"601FC0A3-9632-57E2-AD0A-5F95081BE641","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.jetbrains.intellij",
  "crashReporterKey" : "33D9A4C3-8F13-E387-04B2-53BD5DB29E68",
  "bridgeVersion" : {"build":"20P420","train":"7.0"},
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "asiBacktraces" : ["0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81080343b __exceptionPreprocess + 242\n1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff810352e25 objc_exception_throw + 48\n2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81082b5d6 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0\n3   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138d2161 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 307\n4   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138bef4f -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1247\n5   AppKit                              0x00007ff813a59412 -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50\n6   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138bea69 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42\n7   AppKit                              0x00007ff813a593cb -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 59\n8   AppKit                              0x00007ff8138bcf88 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 354\n9   AppKit                              0x00007ff81388b42a -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 222\n10  AppKit                              0x00007ff81388ab9c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 476\n11  AppKit                              0x00007ff81387f67f loadNib + 420\n12  AppKit                              0x00007ff81387ea67 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 737\n13  AppKit                              0x00007ff81387e691 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201\n14  AppKit                              0x00007ff813bd17a0 -[NSAlert init] + 101\n15  idea                                0x000000010483ca48 -[Launcher buildArgsFor:] + 1416\n16  idea                                0x000000010483cf54 -[Launcher launch] + 340\n17  Foundation                          0x00007ff8115da82c __NSThread__start__ + 1009\n18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8106b0259 _pthread_start + 125\n19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8106abc7b thread_start + 15"],
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":1012779,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":226,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":89637,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":48,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1177046,"symbol":"_CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":414049,"symbol":"-[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled]","symbolLocation":307,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":335695,"symbol":"-[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:]","symbolLocation":1247,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2016274,"symbol":"-[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:]","symbolLocation":50,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":334441,"symbol":"-[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:]","symbolLocation":42,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2016203,"symbol":"-[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:]","symbolLocation":59,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":327560,"symbol":"-[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate]","symbolLocation":354,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":123946,"symbol":"-[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:]","symbolLocation":222,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":121756,"symbol":"-[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:]","symbolLocation":476,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":75391,"symbol":"loadNib","symbolLocation":420,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":72295,"symbol":"+[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:]","symbolLocation":737,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":71313,"symbol":"-[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:]","symbolLocation":201,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":3557280,"symbol":"-[NSAlert init]","symbolLocation":101,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":19016,"symbol":"-[Launcher buildArgsFor:]","symbolLocation":1416,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":20308,"symbol":"-[Launcher launch]","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":362540,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":1009,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":25177,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":7291,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":4}],
  "faultingThread" : 3,
  "threads" : [{"id":170066,"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":5794,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":63101,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":82,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":34586,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":723,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":6537,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":19,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":519438,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":145,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":513914,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1360,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":510896,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":560,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":16162,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":370,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":25360,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2432,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":170079,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":170080,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":4}]},{"triggered":true,"id":170081,"threadState":{"r13":{"value":206158430216},"rax":{"value":0},"rflags":{"value":582},"cpu":{"value":0},"r14":{"value":6},"rsi":{"value":6},"r8":{"value":123145565751904},"cr2":{"value":140704474011336},"rdx":{"value":0},"r10":{"value":0},"r9":{"value":140703403790235},"r15":{"value":22},"rbx":{"value":123145565761536},"trap":{"value":133},"err":{"value":33554760},"r11":{"value":582},"rip":{"value":140703403836174,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"rbp":{"value":123145565752256},"rsp":{"value":123145565752216},"r12":{"value":8451},"rcx":{"value":123145565752216},"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rdi":{"value":8451}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":33550,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":24443,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":263,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":531621,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":123,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":65666,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":241,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4669,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":266,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":118819,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":96,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":62629,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":72965,"symbol":"__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*)","symbolLocation":27,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":72908,"symbol":"__cxa_throw","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":89891,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":302,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":1177046,"symbol":"-[NSException raise]","symbolLocation":9,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":414049,"symbol":"-[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled]","symbolLocation":307,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":335695,"symbol":"-[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:]","symbolLocation":1247,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2016274,"symbol":"-[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:]","symbolLocation":50,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":334441,"symbol":"-[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:]","symbolLocation":42,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2016203,"symbol":"-[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:]","symbolLocation":59,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":327560,"symbol":"-[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate]","symbolLocation":354,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":123946,"symbol":"-[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:]","symbolLocation":222,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":121756,"symbol":"-[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:]","symbolLocation":476,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":75391,"symbol":"loadNib","symbolLocation":420,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":72295,"symbol":"+[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:]","symbolLocation":737,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":71313,"symbol":"-[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:]","symbolLocation":201,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":3557280,"symbol":"-[NSAlert init]","symbolLocation":101,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":19016,"symbol":"-[Launcher buildArgsFor:]","symbolLocation":1416,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":20308,"symbol":"-[Launcher launch]","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":362540,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":1009,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":25177,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":7291,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":170090,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":170091,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703403802624,
    "size" : 237560,
    "uuid" : "0c2fd2c9-777c-3355-b70f-7b1b6e9d1b0b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64h",
    "base" : 140703404441600,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreFoundation",
    "size" : 4820992,
    "uuid" : "dbc459f3-81bb-398a-8f74-3f7392392bb7",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/Versions\/A\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1953.1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4370694144,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "2022.2.3",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.jetbrains.intellij",
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "a4de0629-7887-3eaf-b883-5ae080407e51",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/IntelliJ IDEA.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/idea",
    "name" : "idea",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "IU-222.4345.14"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703400693760,
    "size" : 607568,
    "uuid" : "28fd2071-57f3-3873-87bf-e4f674a82de6",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703404040192,
    "size" : 49144,
    "uuid" : "13b5e252-77d1-31e1-888d-1c5f4426ea87",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703402786816,
    "size" : 561152,
    "uuid" : "5efaf10b-2ec1-32ed-b077-80125e552c8d",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703403712512,
    "size" : 90104,
    "uuid" : "68c48086-22ee-31c9-a457-954d641b9328",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++abi.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++abi.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64h",
    "base" : 140703400448000,
    "size" : 245721,
    "uuid" : "aca7ef61-2853-3699-8c1f-1c0ab93ad6be",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703456219136,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.AppKit",
    "size" : 16797687,
    "uuid" : "817d572e-eb8c-3999-b7a0-68e1c4b47266",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/AppKit.framework\/Versions\/C\/AppKit",
    "name" : "AppKit",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "2299"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703419604992,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.Foundation",
    "size" : 10559479,
    "uuid" : "eca88952-d3af-357e-80d8-4d31b2dc0c26",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Versions\/C\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1953.1"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 140703400087552,
  "size" : 21474836480,
  "uuid" : "840e528a-0c70-3c6a-b7b4-4f05f32ccc51"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=402.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=402.2M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=1.1G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                          216K       23 \nCoreGraphics                         4K        1 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 \nMALLOC                           248.3M       43 \nMALLOC guard page                   48K       10 \nMALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         480.0M        4         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        6 \nStack                             18.0M        6 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         20K        4 \n__CTF                               756        1 \n__DATA                            15.5M      302 \n__DATA_CONST                      13.9M      182 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       652K      107 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       181.4M        5 \n__OBJC_RO                         65.1M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         1982K        2 \n__TEXT                           220.8M      324 \ndyld private memory                256K        1 \nmapped file                       67.6M       15 \nshared memory                      764K       15 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.7G     1057 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space   890.8M     1057 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000215
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62fe74515312cd4599bd3c80",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "MYRIAD_BOOSTS" : "62fe74805312cd4599bd3c81"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000006
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: MacBookPro15,1, BootROM 1916.40.8.0.0 (iBridge: 20.16.420.0.0,0), 6 processors, 6-Core Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630, Intel UHD Graphics 630, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2880 x 1800 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Graphics: Radeon Pro 555X, Radeon Pro 555X, PCIe, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 16 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, Micron, 16ATS2G64HZ-2G6B1
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 16 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, Micron, 16ATS2G64HZ-2G6B1
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Sep 14 2022 18:10:05 version 9.30.489.3.32.5.84 FWID 01-31bf0e8d
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB3.1 Hub
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB2.1 Hub
USB Device: T2Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.5
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.5
```

Above is the Error Log when I open Intellij IDEA, and it just crushed.

It is troubling me. Can anyone offer me a solution for it?

I have uninstalled, reinstalled IDEA, and reinstalled the XCode app. And I hope I can find a method to import those files that were deleted by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash from the IntelliJ IDEA report looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-282172

Check the below locations and see if you have configured `IDEA_VM_OPTIONS` or any IDE-related entries there and remove them, and try to relogin/restart the macOS.

```
~/.profile
~/.zshrc
~/Library/LaunchAgents/jetbrains.vmoptions.plist
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
```

If you have `~/jetbrains.vmoptions.sh`, remove it too.

Comment: Thank you so much! After trying several times, I solved it! It turns out that I had cracked these apps before I deleted the cracking files. After deleting the cracking files and scripts the Intellij stopped working. Now I have redownloaded PyCharm as well as others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Step: In the window that appears, enter the path "/Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/LaunchAgents/"
2. Step: Locate the file named "jetbrains.vmoptions.plist" and double-click to open it.
3. Step: Within the file, find and remove all instances of the expression "launchctl setenv "*_OPTIONS"".
4. Step: Save the file and close it.
5. Step: Restart your Mac.